# how to save an svg file in php

Tags: javascript, php, svg

how to do this in php. Do i need to use an php library

```
<svg
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="360" height="180">
   <circle class="little" cx="180" cy="45" r="12"/>
   <circle class="little" cx="60" cy="90" r="12"/>
   <circle class="little" cx="300" cy="135" r="12"/>
</svg>
```

Hi i have an xml data above i just want this to save in my folder: images/circle.svg

Is there anyone here can help me.
Thank you very much

Comment: What do you mean, "i have an svg above"? Is it a file? Do you have it rendered on a client? Is it on a printout in your purse?

Comment: im sorry i mean xml data to save as circle.svg file

Comment: Of course; SVG is always XML. The point is, where do you have it?

Comment: i just want to save it as circle.svg in my folder

Comment: I don't know how to ask this any clearer. For the third time, I know that you want to save it, but *where is it before that?* (I feel like the [security guard in Freddy Got Fingered](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P5ip-Gglcmc).)

Comment: the data will be dynamic for better undestanding i just hard coded it. Is it clearer now?

Comment: just write into a normal file.. if you reading it from anywhere use fwrite() or file_put_contents()

Comment: Are you reading from a URL or from a file or a post content explain clearly

Comment: Of course it's dynamic, otherwise you'd just use an editor. You still completely managed to avoid saying if the data is located clientside or serverside, and whether it's a string or part of DOM. I give up, voting to close.

Comment: its not important where it came from. I just need the data to save as image  file as circle.svg

Answer (score 6):

So you've got the data stored as a variable, right? Easy peasy.

`file_put_contents('images/circle.svg', $SVGData);`

Comment: i did this right i just wondering why they need to know where the data came from?????

Comment: Because the answer is very different (and actually interesting) if you need to extract it from DOM and submit from clientside (possibly using AJAX, to not destroy the currently rendered page). If you already have it in PHP in string form, it is completely and utterly irrelevant that it is SVG; you could have asked "how do I write a string to file in PHP", and tagged it just as `php`. If you went one step further, you could have googled that exact phrase and found a bunch of pages that show you exactly this. And you could have spared both your time and mine just saying "it's in a PHP string".

Answer (score 0):

Below code working 100%, hope it will help in your project.

```
<?php
ob_start();
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="100" height="100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg>';

$content = ob_get_clean();

if(file_put_contents("circle.svg", $content)) { // Filename for storing purpose
    echo "Success";
}
else {
    echo "Failed to save file";
}
?>
```